# Procedure not running in toad asking for the variable

Tags: database, oracle, toad

I'm using TOAD for Oracle.  I'm trying to execute a stored procedure with two parameters - one IN and one OUT.  It looks like this:

PROCEDURE get_stuff (
      parm_1   IN       VARCHAR2,
      parm_2   OUT      currefcursor)

In the SQL Editor window in TOAD, I've tried various things to no avail.  I'm sure this is something simple that I'm missing, 'cause I've tried all sorts of things I've seen in other solutions here at Experts Exchange, but can't get past various errors.  Here's what I think should work from what I've seen here:

```
 var p1 VARCHAR2 := 'some text';
 var p2 currefcursor;

 EXEC get_stuff( :p1, :p2 );
```

When I run this, though, the SQL Editor pops up a window titled 'Variables' that appears to be looking for a value.  No matter whether I put something in the 'Value' textbox or not, when I click OK, it says:

```
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

and highlights the 'var' in front of p1.

Please tell me what I'm missing!
Status Solved Priority Medium Security Public Views 21999

Answer (score 0):

As the second parameter is `OUT`, you have to declare the variable which will accept that value. Here's how; I don't know what `currefcursor` type is - I guess you do.

```
declare
  l_out currefcursor;
begin
  get_stuff(:p1, l_out);
end;
/
```

---

A simple option to view the result would be this: put this code into the editor and run it as a script; the result will be displayed in the Script Output tab.

```
variable l_out currefcursor
exec get_stuff(:p1, :l_out);
print l_out
```

---

Or, you could even create a *wrapper* function which returns *cursor*, and then select from it:

```
create or replace function f_get_stuff(p1 in number) 
  return currefcursor
is
  l_out currefcursor;
begin
  get_stuff(p1, l_out);
  return l_out;
end;
/

select f_get_stuff(:p1) from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Toad to execute without writing the execution harness yourself as well. Here is one method using the Schema Browser. Select your object and right-click > Execute.

[image]

You are presented with a dialog asking for your input parameters. Set your inputs and you can see the generated execution harness below. You can also use this generated code as an educational guide to see one method of writing the code yourself.

[image]

Click OK and your function/procedure is executed and results are shown.

[image]